# Keyrings used for installation

Tags: onion-services

I have fairly simple question regarding step 3. and step 4. in the following guide:
https://support.torproject.org/apt/tor-deb-repo/

Do they depend on each other? I tried to install Tor without step 4. and it worked. I installed it on Ubuntu. Is it really necessary? If yes how? Whats the difference. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Great point! IMHO the installation **must** be done strictly from source optimized for a hardware it's executed on